# Sample R code to extract specific columns

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
      FlightID FareClass FareClassRank FareValue Bookings
1 YULCDG215135         Q             1       100        5
2 YULCDG215135         X             2       150        7
3 YULCDG215135         V             3       200        4
4 YULCDG215135         Y             4      1000        2
5 YULCDG215136         Q             1       120        1
6 YULCDG215136         X             2       200        4
7 YULCDG215136         V             3       270        5
8 YULCDG215136         Y             4       900       15
```

Question: I need to write simple code in R:

For each flight, the ratio of the value of the fare class to the value of its next fare class.

As example, X is the next fare class of Q, V is the next fare class of X, and so on.

The ratio for flight YULCDG215135 is 100/150 = 0.6667 for X, 150/200=0.75 for V and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `by`.

```
by(df, df$FlightID, function(x) c(NA, exp(-diff(log(x$FareValue)))))
#df$FlightID: YULCDG215135
#[1]        NA 0.6666667 0.7500000 0.2000000
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$FlightID: YULCDG215136
#[1]        NA 0.6000000 0.7407407 0.3000000
```

Or alternatively using `ave`

```
transform(df, ratio = ave(FareValue, FlightID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, exp(-diff(log(x))))))
#      FlightID FareClass FareClassRank FareValue Bookings     ratio
#1 YULCDG215135         Q             1       100        5        NA
#2 YULCDG215135         X             2       150        7 0.6666667
#3 YULCDG215135         V             3       200        4 0.7500000
#4 YULCDG215135         Y             4      1000        2 0.2000000
#5 YULCDG215136         Q             1       120        1        NA
#6 YULCDG215136         X             2       200        4 0.6000000
#7 YULCDG215136         V             3       270        5 0.7407407
#8 YULCDG215136         Y             4       900       15 0.3000000
```

The trick in both cases is to log-transform `FareValue` so that we can use `diff`, and then to invert the transformation (using `exp`) to give the ratio.

Answer (score 2):

```
require(dplyr) 
df %>% 
group_by(FlightID) %>% 
arrange(FareClassRank) %>%
mutate(ratio=FareValue/lead(FareValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df$FareOverNext <- unlist(lappy(split(df$FareValue, df$FlightID), {
 c(1, x[1:(length(x) - 1)] / x[2:length(x)])
}))
```

**EDIT:**

Added `lapply` and `split` thanks to @thelatemail comment.

Comment: This causes the ratio to bleed over from one `FlightID` to the next though.

Comment: You are right. It needs an split. I will fix it in a moment.